# How to connect a Java Desktop Application to an online database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I developed a desktop application and for some reason, I'll like to upload the contents of my database to an online or remote database.

What I really want is just a way to go around this or preferably a database URL that can help solve this problem. I've tried so many formats but not seems to be working.

e.g

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://charlinktravels.com/charlink_test","username","password");

Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://198.154.249.141:80/charlink_test?user=username&password=password");
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? Do you actually have a database server?

Comment: for the record, MYSQL works on port 3306, the connection string is usually `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/charlink_test` pass the username and password as arguments.

Comment: @AnanthaSharma You can leave the port out, it will use the default (3306): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

Answer (score 2):

This will work

```
  String url="jdbc:mysql://198.154.249.141:80/charlink_test"
  Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "username", "password");
```

This will work,But make sure you have permission to connect that server and data base up and running.

Comment: And make sure that `username` is for a mysql user on that IP address, not (only) localhost. To prevent easy change the standard port to something far above 1000. Port 80 for firewalls? Igit.

Comment: Can i know what "charlink_test" is?

Comment: @USer54564213 that's your database name

Answer (score 0):

I have no no idea what "I've tried so many formats but not seems to be working" means.

There's only one format for the URL connection string; it's in the JDBC driver docs.

You have another problem if you're giving it what you think are correct values, in the correct format, but you're still not able to connect.

It'll help to post what you think the correct URL is and what the error message you get back says.

Who owns that remote database?  Do you have credentials to log in and manipulate the database?  If not, you'll have to get permission.